# Javascript Morris.js TypeError: a is undefined Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, morris.js

I have the  following controller which passes data from mysql database to json

```
function chart_js() {

        $rows = '';
        $query = "SELECT clnt_id,date_added FROM job_card ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0, 5";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $total_rows = $result->num_rows;
        if ($result) {
            $rows = $result->result_array();
        }

        echo json_encode($rows);
    }
```

And the data is supposed to be used to plot/chart a line graph on my view using morris.js The following is my script and html code :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Client Jobs Past 7 days
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="acctregs" style="height: 300px;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
        <script>



            var acct_regs = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/operations/chart_js";
            var acctregs = new Morris.Line({
                // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
                element: 'acctregs',
                // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
                // the chart.
                data: acct_regs,
                // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
                xkey: 'date_added',
                // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
                ykeys: ['clnt_id'],
                // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
                // chart.
                labels: ['Value'],
                dateFormat: function (x) {
                    return new Date(x).toString().split("00:00:00")[0];
                }
            });

        </script>
```

Which is supposed to get data from the  above mentioned function chart_js and use it to plot the graphs. But I keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: a is undefined


...,h,i,j,k,l;return"number"==typeof a?a:(c=a.match(/^(\d+) Q(\d)$/),e=a.match(/^(\...
```

The problem is with the  url which is used to get the  data from the database, since when I use static data it works, what is the  bast way to pass this url :

```
var acct_regs = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/operations/chart_js";
```

Comment: Have you tried [site_url](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) like this `<?php echo site_url('operations/char_js'); ?>`

Comment: @jagad89 when I use site_url I get the  following error : SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 

var acct_regs = http://localhost:8888/unique_loo/operations/char_js;

Comment: `var acct_regs = "<?php echo site_url('operations/char_js'); ?>";`

Comment: Try and place the `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>` in the `<head></head>` area.